# How do I change the alpha of an NSBezierpath filled with an image?

Tags: cocoa, drawing

Note: this is on OSX NOT iOs...

NSColor has a neat helper method called "colorWithPatternImage" that allows you to treat any image as a "fill" on, for instance, an NSBezierPath.

I would like to use this to create multiple overlapping squares that contain images whose opacity I can change.

The trouble is the following:

```
// ok - solid white
NSColor *fillColor = [NSColor whiteColor]; 

// ok - same as above
fillColor = [[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0];

// ok - alpha of 50% (light grey)
fillColor = [[NSColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

// ok - fills with content of NSImage backgroundImage
fillColor = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];

// ok - same as above
fillColor = [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0];

// FAILS! - any value less than 1.0 acts like alpha is 0.0
fillColor = [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9];
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I did try first re-drawing the NSImage with an alpha and then using it as a "patternImage." While that does properly apply the alpha to the image itself, it does nothing to the path, so you end up with a "dimmed" but opaque image.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the image data to have alpha less than 1 but greater than 0 before you create a pattern out of it?

Comment: That made it worse, in the sense that the alpha is applied, but then colorWithAlphaComponent ignores it completely. I am beginning to suspect a bug in NSColor